# Jquery - How to animate content within the owl carousel slider?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I want to do the following animation to appear on a single slide of owl carousel.

The animation is;

There are three books,
[image]

**first animation** : I want to slide all three books together from left to center
[image]

**second animation** : Then, I want to move the **book 1** slightly to the left and the **book 3** while the middle book which is **book 2** would remain in the center

[image]

Currently I  have managed to bring all three books to the center (which is the first animatio) using the below jquery code;

```
$(".banner-slider").on("translate.owl.carousel", function () {
    $(".slide-anime-img").removeClass("animated fadeInRight").css("opacity", "0"),
        $(".temp-slide").removeClass("animated zoom").css("opacity", "0"),
        $(".owl-vis").removeClass("animated fadeInRight").css({ "-webkit-animation-delay": ".6s", "animation-delay": ".6s", "opacity": "0" }),
        $(".banner-content").removeClass("animated fadeInRight").css("opacity", "0"),
        $(".banner-content1 ").removeClass("animated fadeInLeft").css("opacity", "0"),
        $(".banner-content1 .b1i2").removeClass("animated mymove ").css({ "-webkit-animation-delay": "6s", "animation-delay": "6s", "opacity": "0", "animation": "animation: mymove 5s 1;", "animation-timing-function": "linear", }),
        $(".banner-content1 .b1i1").removeClass("animated mymove").css({ "-webkit-animation-delay": ".3s", "animation-delay": ".3s", "opacity": "0" }),
        $(".banner-content h1").removeClass("animated fadeInRight").css({ "-webkit-animation-delay": ".6s", "animation-delay": ".6s", "opacity": "0" }),
        $(".banner-content p").removeClass("animated fadeInRight").css({ "-webkit-animation-delay": ".6s", "animation-delay": ".6s", "opacity": "0" }),
        $(".banner-content a.cmn-button").removeClass("animated slideInLeft").css("opacity", "0")
}),
    $(".banner-slider").on("translated.owl.carousel", function () {
        $(".slide-anime-img").addClass("animated fadeInRight").css("opacity", "1"),
            $(".temp-slide").addClass("animated zoom").css("opacity", "1"),
            $(".owl-vis").addClass("animated fadeInRight").css({ "-webkit-animation-delay": ".6s", "animation-delay": ".6s", "opacity": "0" }),
            $(".banner-content").addClass("animated fadeInRight").css("opacity", "1"),
            $(".banner-content1 ").addClass("animated fadeInLeft").css("opacity", "0"),
            $(".banner-content1 .b1i2").addClass("animated mymove").css({ "-webkit-animation-delay": "6s", "animation-delay": "6s", "opacity": "0","animation": "animation: mymove 5s 1;", "animation-timing-function": "linear",  }),
            $(".banner-content1 .b1i1").addClass("animated mymove").css({ "-webkit-animation-delay": ".3s", "animation-delay": ".3s", "opacity": "0" }),
            $(".banner-content h1").addClass("animated fadeInRight").css({ "-webkit-animation-delay": ".6s", "animation-delay": ".6s", "opacity": "0" }),
            $(".banner-content p").addClass("animated fadeInRight").css({ "-webkit-animation-delay": ".6s", "animation-delay": ".6s", "opacity": "0" }),
            $(".banner-content a.cmn-button").addClass("animated slideInLeft").css("opacity", "1")
    });
```

Here is the html part;

```
<section class="banner-section">
<div class="owl-carousel banner-slider">
    <div class="banner-slider-item1">

        <img class="img-fluid temp-slide3" src="~/Images/t2.jpg" style="    bottom: -69px;"/>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="banner-content1">
                        <div class="bookimgs">

                            <img class="b1i2 animated fadeInLeft" src="~/Images/b.png" />

                            <img class="b1i1 animated fadeInLeft" src="~/Images/c.png" />
                            <img class="b1i3 animated fadeInLeft" src="~/Images/a.png" />

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner-slider-item1">

        <img class="img-fluid temp-slide2" src="~/Images/home-slider.jpg" />
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="banner-content">
                        <div class="owl-dots owl-vis">
                            <button role="button" class="owl-dot active"><span></span></button>
                            <button role="button" class="owl-dot "><span></span></button>
                            <button role="button" class="owl-dot "><span></span></button>
                            <button role="button" class="owl-dot "><span></span></button>
                        </div>
                        <h1 class="banner-content-head">
                            The finest notebooks for the best brands
                        </h1>

                        <p>for a new freedom – and more than just<br /> beautiful books with a logo</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner-slider-item1">

        <img class="img-fluid temp-slide2" src="~/Images/slide2.jpg" />
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="banner-content">
                        <div class="owl-dots owl-vis">
                            <button role="button" class="owl-dot "><span></span></button>
                            <button role="button" class="owl-dot active"><span></span></button>
                            <button role="button" class="owl-dot "><span></span></button>
                            <button role="button" class="owl-dot "><span></span></button>
                        </div>
                        <h1 class="banner-content-head">
                            A reliable and multifunctional platform for business
                        </h1>

                        <p>for a new freedom – and more than just<br /> beautiful books with a logo</p>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- banner-slider-item end -->
    <div class="banner-slider-item1">

        <img class="img-fluid temp-slide2" src="~/Images/slide4.jpg" />
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="banner-content">
                        <div class="owl-dots owl-vis">
                            <button role="button" class="owl-dot "><span></span></button>
                            <button role="button" class="owl-dot "><span></span></button>
                            <button role="button" class="owl-dot active"><span></span></button>
                            <button role="button" class="owl-dot "><span></span></button>
                        </div>
                        <h1 class="banner-content-head">A reliable and multifunctional platform for business</h1>
                        <p>for a new freedom – and more than just<br /> beautiful books with a logo</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner-slider-item1">

        <img class="img-fluid temp-slide2" src="~/Images/slide3.jpg" />
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="banner-content">
                        <div class="owl-dots owl-vis">
                            <button role="button" class="owl-dot "><span></span></button>
                            <button role="button" class="owl-dot "><span></span></button>
                            <button role="button" class="owl-dot "><span></span></button>
                            <button role="button" class="owl-dot active"><span></span></button>
                        </div>
                        <h1 class="banner-content-head">
                            Style, material & colours in unison
                        </h1>
                        <p>for a new freedom – and more than just<br /> beautiful books with a logo</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- banner-slider-item end -->

</div>
```

Kindly help me to do the whole animation using jquery

Comment: Why do you need jQuery animation to achieve this? You should checkout CSS animations which are way more simple and performant. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: because its owl carousel and css animation wont repeat the animation in active slide. css  animation do it only once

Comment: I am not sure about Own Carousel, but you can have continuous (repeating) animations in CSS as well. Also do check out transitions using this link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp
The only thing you need to figure out is how and when you apply animation classes using JavaScript.

Comment: i tried but its not working